# How can I track the work of a function that downloads a file from the site

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, jupyter

I am writing a program that should download a large tar file (1.5 GB) the Download is successful on small files and I can check it by downloading. But with a large file this will have to wait quite a long time. How can I track the process of downloading this file?

```py
directory = os.getcwd()
path = directory + '/europarl.tgz'
print(directory)
print(path)

if "europarl.tgz" in os.listdir(directory):
    print("yep")
else:
    print("nope")
    urlretrieve.content('http://www.statmt.org/europarl/v7/europarl.tgz', path)
    print("yep")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a 3rd argument to `urlretrieve`, called `reporthook`. It has to be a function accepting 3 numeric parameters: A `chunk` number, `block size` and the `total size of the download` (-1 if unknown).

For more info consult [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html). The function could look something like this:

```
def reporthook(chunk_n, block_size, download_size):
    global start_time
    if chunk_n == 0:
        start_time = time.time()
        return
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    progress_size = int(chunk_n * block_size)
    speed = int(progress_size / (1024 * duration))
    percent = int(chunk_n * block_size * 100 / download_size)
    sys.stdout.write("\r...%d%%, %d MB, %d KB/s, %d seconds passed" %
                    (percent, progress_size / (1024 * 1024), speed, duration))
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook)
```

You can also check the package `tqdm`  which displays progress bars.